# How can I make jackson throwing error when a value for primitive is not set in json?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, primitive-types

Given the code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue("{}", Foo.class));
    }

    public static class Foo {
        long id;

        public long getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return "For(id=" + id + ')'; }
    }
}
```

I want exception thrown instead of `0` in the `id` field.
I tried different things like `@JsonProperty(required = true)`, `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)` but it does not work and still just silently sets `0`

How do I force it to throw an exception when there is no value for the field or it is set to null in JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowlendge that's only supported when using contructors. Feature that controls it is `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`. You need to annotate the constructor, which jackson will use with `@JsonCreator`, and arguments in the constructor with `@JsonProperty`. Like this:

```
public class Foo {

    long id;

    @JsonCreator
    public Foo(@JsonProperty("id") long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "For(id=" + id + ')';
    }
}
```

And enable the feature for the mapper.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES, true);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{}", Foo.class));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** That's only for properties missing from content. If you need to specifically fail `null` properties(not applicable for you case, since you use primitives, but adding for completeness), you need this feature `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`. You can enable it the same way as the other property in the example.

Comment: That sucks. They should have made an option for normal properties as well...
Thank you!

Comment: @lowercase93 You are welcome. You can check the edit, i added how to fail null values from content. `FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES` fails null as well, but that's only for your case, because you are working with primitives. If you work with objects, and need to fail nulls, then you would need the second feature i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is in @Chaosfire's answer, there is another feature that fits even better: [DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)

> Feature that determines whether encountering of JSON null is an error when deserializing into Java primitive types (like 'int' or 'double'). If it is, a InvalidNullException is thrown to indicate this; if not, default value is used (0 for 'int', 0.0 for double, same defaulting as what JVM uses).
>
> Feature is disabled by default.